# UPDATE query with CASE WHEN in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table `TABLE1` with 3 columns `NAME, ROLLNO, CASHDATE`.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1
(
    NAME VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL, 
    ROLLNO NUMBER(4) NOT NULL, 
    CASHDATE VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('SAMY', 1234, '15990101');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('TOMY', 1324, '15990101');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('DANY', 1342, '15990101');
```

TABLE1 looks like:

```
NAME         ROLLNO      CASHDATE
----------------------------------
SAMY         1234        15990101
TOMY         1324        15990101
DANY         1342        15990101
```

CASHDATE value is in the form of YYYYMMDD

I have a second table `TABLE2` with 3 columns `NAME, ID, ID_DATE`:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE2
(
     NAME VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL, 
     ID VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL, 
     ID_DATE TIMESTAMP(3)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES('SAMY', '01', timestamp '2021-08-21 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES('SAMY', 'A1', timestamp '2018-08-19 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES('TOMY', '01', timestamp '2021-08-22 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES('TOMY', 'B1', timestamp '2000-08-15 00:00:00');
```

TABLE2 looks like:

```
NAME         ID        ID_DATE
--------------------------------------------------------
SAMY         01        21-AUG-2021 12.00.00.000000000 AM
SAMY         A1        19-AUG-2018 12.00.00.000000000 AM
TOMY         01        22-AUG-2021 12.00.00.000000000 AM 
TOMY         B1        15-AUG-2000 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

And I have a third table `TABLE3` with 2 columns `NAME, SEC_DATE`:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE3 
(
    NAME VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL, 
    SEC_DATE TIMESTAMP(3)
);

INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES('SAMY', timestamp '2021-08-21 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES('TOMY', timestamp '2021-08-22 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO TABLE3 VALUES('DANY', timestamp '2021-08-29 00:00:00');
```

TABLE3 looks like:

```
NAME         SEC_DATE
----------------------------------------------
SAMY         21-AUG-2021 12.00.00.000000000 AM
TOMY         22-AUG-2021 12.00.00.000000000 AM 
DANY         29-AUG-2021 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

As we see I have a TABLE1 having CASHDATE value as 15990101 which is default value.

So we need to UPDATE CASHDATE column which is having 15990101 in TABLE1 based on following conditions.

1. First it checks in TABLE2 based on NAME in TABLE2, if there is a record having same NAME with ID = '01' then ID_DATE value should update in CASHDATE column of TABLE1.
2. If it is not found in TABLE2 based on NAME with ID = '01', then it checks in TABLE3 and based on NAME only if there is a record, we need to update (SEC_DATE - 1) value in CASHDATE column of TABLE1.

Finally after update, the result TABLE1 looks like:

```
 NAME         ROLLNO      CASHDATE
----------------------------------
 SAMY         1234        20210821   --This record found in TABLE2
 TOMY         1324        20210822   --This record found in TABLE2
 DANY         1342        20210828   --This record found in TABLE3 (SEC_DATE - 1)
```

I understand we need to update statement but I am not sure using CASE WHEN in UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `COALESCE` in combination with subqueries for this:

```
update table1 t1
set cashdate =
  coalesce
  (
    (select to_char(id_date, 'yyyymmdd') from table2 t2 where t2.name = t1.name and t2.id = '01'),
    (select to_char(sec_date - interval '1' day, 'yyyymmdd') from table3 t3 where t3.name = t1.name),
    '15990101'
  )
where cashdate = '15990101';
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b6c5b08f5b303a23d26e5349228ee301

Answer (score 2):

From  my point of view, a simple option is a two-step option, i.e. two updates. In this case, I actually prefer `MERGE` over `UPDATE`.

Initial `table1` contents:

```
SQL> select * From table1;

NAME     ROLLNO CASHDATE
---- ---------- --------
SAMY       1234 15990101
TOMY       1324 15990101
DANY       1342 15990101
```

Update `cashdate` based on `table2`'s contents (that's your 1st condition):

```
SQL> merge into table1 a
  2    using table2 b
  3    on (a.name = b.name)
  4    when matched then update set
  5      a.cashdate = to_char(b.id_date, 'yyyymmdd')
  6      where a.cashdate = '15990101'
  7        and b.id = '01';

2 rows merged.
```

Update `cashdate` based on `table3`'s contents (that's your 2st condition) (`not exists` is here to skip rows already updated in previous step):

```
SQL> merge into table1 a
  2    using table3 c
  3    on (c.name = a.name)
  4    when matched then update set
  5      a.cashdate = to_char(c.sec_date - 1, 'yyyymmdd')
  6      where a.cashdate = '15990101'
  7        and not exists (select null from table2 b
  8                        where b.name = a.name
  9                          and b.id = '01'
 10                       );

1 row merged.
```

Final result:

```
SQL> select * from table1;

NAME     ROLLNO CASHDATE
---- ---------- --------
SAMY       1234 20210821
TOMY       1324 20210822
DANY       1342 20210828

SQL>
```

Comment: For example, in TABLE1, I have 10 rows...Out of 10 rows, I have 6 rows having CASHDATE as default value i.e. 15990101 and other 4 rows they are having someother CASHDATE value which is valid...I want to update only the records having CASHDATE value as 15990101 in TABLE1..It should update only 6 rows...Remaining 4 rows shouldn't get effected by these merge statements

Comment: Add that condition into WHERE clauses, then.

Comment: ... which also means you can remove the `NOT EXISTS` clause from the second update. If the value is still on default after the update from table2, you want to try the update from table3

Comment: Good catch, Thorsten! Thank you; I'll leave it to the OP, though.

Comment: Why did you write "SELECT NULL FROM TABLE2 b"- Why NULL here?

Comment: Could've been *anything*

Comment: @Johnbsdk10: It is common to `select null` in a `[NOT] EXISTS` clause. Some people write `select 1` instead, others use `select *` which is not possible though when the subquery is an aggregation. As this is just to check whether a matching row exists, it doesn't matter what you put in the `SELECT` clause as long as it's valid. My preference, too, is `select null`. If you prefer to write `select 'a matching row'` or the like instead, go ahead ;-)

Comment: Instead of NOT EXISTS statement, Can we use " a.name not in (select name from table2 b where b.id = '01') "

Comment: @Johnbsdk10: Yes, that is possible. It is important, though, to know that this works because table2.name can never be null. `NOT IN` fails when the data set contains nulls. Anyway, as mentioned, you probably won't need the clause anyway, because the default date tells you already that the row has not been updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the data and update the table rows from the query result. This is called an updateable query. The great advantage is that we only update rows that we want updated (in your case rows that are on default value and have a match in table2 and/or table3).

For a query to be updateable, Oracle must see it guaranteed that there is just one target value selected per row. This means that we need unique constraints to ensure that joining table2 and table3 rows to a table1 row still results in no more than one row per table1 row.

The constraints needed here are

- table2: primary key (name, id)
- table3: primary key (name)

With these constraints in place, Oracle should be able to update our query:

```
update
(
  select
    t1.cashdate,
    coalesce(t2.id_date, t3.sec_date - interval '1' day) as found_date
  from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2 on t2.name = t1.name and t2.id = '01'
  left join table3 t3 on t3.name = t1.name
  where t1.cashdate = '15990101'
  and coalesce(t2.id_date, t3.sec_date - interval '1' day) is not null
)
set cashdate = to_char(found_date, 'yyyymmdd');
```

This may still fail. It really depends on whether Oracle considers this query updateable. It should (and it does in Oracle 18c, as you can see in the demo inked below), but sometimes Oracle struggles with such queries. You'll have to try whether this already works in Oracle 11g.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=36287406a7f5591d4b53df4a7b990ef6